# How to write one to many classes c#

Tags: c#

Here is my problem: I need to represent a one to many relationship. One Company has many Stores.
This is my code:

```
public class Company 
{
    public int Id;

    public string Name;

    public string Email;

    public Guid GUID;
}

public class Store 
{

    public int Id;

    public int CompanyId;

    public string Name;

    public int NoOfEmployees;

    public Guid GUID;
}
```

My question is: how this works without using virtual and hashsets? is this implementation ok?

Thank you.

Comment: it might be handy for Company to have a List<Store>, and indeed for Store to have a Company property...it makes navigation easier

Comment: If it's ok depends on what you plan to do with it. And the criteria "without using virtual and hashsets" is a little unclear.... I'd prefer to give the `Company` class a property like `public List<Store> Stores {get;set;}` That will contain all the stores belonging to that company. So you don't always have to reverse lookup which stores have the correct `CompanyId`.

Comment: I do not agree that virtual properties or collections on the entity make navigation any easier.... What you have done is absolutely fine, one change I would make is that you wouldn't need `int Id` because if store **should** have a company then there should only be the `CompanyId` as the primary and foreign key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use simply a `List` where you would save all the Stores that one company has.

```
public class Company 
{
    public int Id;

    public string Name;

    public string Email;

    public Guid GUID;
    // List of all Stores
    public List<Store> AllTheStores;

    public Company()
    {
        AllTheStores = new List<Store>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The property: `public int CompanyId;` makes only really sense if more than one `Company` can have the same `Store`. Otherwise you could access the stores via the Company:

```
Company c = new Company();

Store s = c.AllTheStores.Find(x=>x.Name == "MyStore");

// or 
List<Store> largeStores = c.AllTheStores.Where(x=>x.NoOfEmployees > 200).ToList();
```

Comment: why is this necessary?

Comment: It isn't necessary

Comment: @Ovidiu do you mean why is the List necessary?

Comment: @Ovidiu Maybe it's about companyId. If that so then it will work as unique identifier to find any company.In some case company name maybe same.

Comment: @Ovidiu in your case the purpose to find unique companies and stores will also be served by Guid

Comment: @Ovidiu Think about it semantically, a store and stores. Stores are a collection of a type called store. you may find closure in this manner of thinking

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying

> One Company has many Stores.

In this statement your answer is.

use  `Company` class as follow, instead of putting `companyID` in `Store` class

```
public class Company 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Email;
    public Guid GUID;

    // put a List of all Stores
    public List<Store> Stores;
}
```

Comment: "In this statement your answer is" brilliant! +1 for the Yoda sentence.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer the question how this works.

Consider you have the id of the company you want to get all the stores for, you can simply do:

```
using (var dbcontext = new DbContext())
{
    var stores = await dbcontext.Stores.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).ToListAsync();
}
```

**You do not need navigation properties.** I never have them, they have only ever caused me issues, I'm not saying they will cause you issues. They're just a convenience thing (from what it seems) which in my opinion obscures the underlying SQL representation and the queries EF could be running. Now, there are going to be few queries which you actually care about EF generating, when you get to them, you may find that navigation properties are hindering you.

If you want to save records, again, just assign each `Store` a real `Company.Id` and you will fulfill the foreign key obligations.

One change you could make (if this applies to your case) is that you can remove `int Id` and use the `CompanyId` as the primary and foreign key

```
public class Store 
{

    // public int Id; just remove this

    public int CompanyId; // make this a foreign key using fluent or attributes.

    public string Name;

    public int NoOfEmployees;

    public Guid GUID;
}
```

This makes sure you retain the 1 to Many relationship, **if those many should only exist for one company**. If not then don't worry about the above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the company class object itself instead of just having CompanyId in the Store class.

```
public class Company 
{
    public int Id;

    public string Name;

    public string Email;

    public Guid GUID;

    public List<Store> Stores;
}

public class Store 
{

    public int Id;

    public Company Company; // Can get CompanyId using StoreObj.Company.Id

    public string Name;

    public int NoOfEmployees;

    public Guid GUID;
}
```